# Error "LB: Transpiled file would overwrite source file. Aborted!"

Tags: atom-editor, babeljs

I've been given a coding task as part of a job interview it's a little outside my ken but I'm trying it anyway. They've given me their boilerplate and asked me to make certain changes. It is a React app built with webpack.

When I try to edit a file [addendum: I should have said "edit and save"], I get the Error "LB: Transpiled file would overwrite source file. Aborted!"

I assume the "LB" refers to language-babel. I can get it to work by disabling language-babel. Maybe I'm confused, but aren't source files exactly what I want to edit? I've never had this problem on any other project on which I've worked.

I've searched and can't find much on this error. I'm on Windows 10 with Atom 1.19.7 X64 and language-babel 2.75.2.

The `.babelrc` that came with the boilerplate is:
```

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "plugins": [
    ["import", [{
      "libraryName": "antd",
      "style": "css"
    }, {
      "libraryName": "lodash",
      "libraryDirectory": "",
      "camel2DashComponentName": false,
    }, {
      "libraryName": "components",
      "libraryDirectory": "",
      "camel2DashComponentName": false,
    }, {
      "libraryName": "HOCS",
      "libraryDirectory": "",
      "camel2DashComponentName": false,
    }]],
      "transform-runtime",
      "transform-class-properties",
      "transform-object-rest-spread",
      "dynamic-import-node",
  ]
}
```

```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Take the sentence that starts, "When I try to edit a file, I get the Error...." Taken literally, that would mean that Atom itself is preventing you from saving files. This doesn't seem likely to me (it's much more likely that the error is presented by Webpack when you run it), but it's also not impossible. Someone *could* make an Atom package that did this. And you've tagged your question as `atom-editor`. You should revise your question to eliminate any ambiguity.

Comment: It might also help to show us what sort of files you're trying to change. What does the directory tree look like? What are the files named?

Comment: Sorry, I mean when I "edit and save". I was trying to edit and save JS files. Now maybe I'm wondering if the issue with that it is trying to transpile it back into the file (the "source") that I was editing. That would kind of make sense. I know I've used it to edit JSX files that get transpiled into JS. But these are files labelled JS with JSX in them. (Forgive me, but I'm still learning the non coding part of coding.)

Comment: Where was the error coming from? What files were you trying to change? `.js` files can have JSX in them. Those files also get transpiled, and that shouldn't be the problem.